# React Hooks useContext not allowing state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global, use-context

I am using a global state with useContext in React Hooks and get the following error:

```
"Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."
```

I want to access and update the state from the context.

My App.js:

```
import { Cart } from "./Cart"

const App = () => {

  const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState('0');

  return (<BrowserRouter>

    <Switch>

      <Cart.Provider value={{ cartTotal, setCartTotal }}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/payment" component={Payment} />
      </Cart.Provider>

    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter >)
}
```

My Cart.js (for creating the context):

```
import { createContext } from "react"

export const Cart = createContext(null) // tried "[[], () => { }]" here instead of null
```

My Home.js (for accessing the context):

```
import { Cart } from '../Cart'

const { cartTotal, setCartTotal } = useContext(Cart)
```

I cant render right now, something about the object React doesn't like, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: add import React from 'react' to each file

Comment: also add import {useContext} from 'react' to Home.js

Comment: also add import {useState} from 'react' to App.js. I hope that you just didn't paste all imports here because there are a lot of other missed :)

Comment: No only useContext related are posted, solved already however so nice job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close in the initial value for the cart context. It should match the types of the context value you later pass in the provider. Your context value is an object with `cartTotal` and `setCartTotal` keys, and the value types are string and function, respectively.

```
const Cart = createContext({
  cartTotal: '',
  setCartTotal: () => {},
});
```

See [Updating context from a nested component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

Additionally, you will want to render the `Switch` within the provider so it is directly rendering the `Route` components.

```
const App = () => {
  const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState('0');

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Cart.Provider value={{ cartTotal, setCartTotal }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/payment" component={Payment} />
        </Switch>
      </Cart.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
};
```